# Criteria for inclusions in co-product to be monos

Tags: category-theory

In category of sets and functions, we observe that inclusions into the sum object (i.e. the disjoint union) are monos. I wanted to see what causes such a behaviour. Following is one criteria that I see as one of the requirements for such a behaviour to exist.

We define a binary relation $\leq$: Let $A, B$ be objects in some undetermined category $C$. $A\leq B$ if and only if $\exists i:A\hookrightarrow B$. (Please let me know if there is more appropriate symbol for this relation).

Criterion: Let $C$ be any category. If  for all objects $A, B \in C$, ($A\leq B \ \vee B\leq A$), then inclusion maps for any sum object, if it exists, are monos.

Proof follows from the fact that for any maps $f, g, h$ such that $f=h\circ g$, if $f$ is mono, then $g$ is mono as well. More specifically, one can have 1 mono from $\leq$, say $i:A\hookrightarrow B$, and the other one will be the idenity on B, then since these maps must factor through (Please correct me if I am using non-standard or even wrong terminology) the inclusion maps, one can use the above fact to individually show that both inclusions must be monos.

**My questions**:

1. Is there any other criterion which is more fundamental i.e. from which my criterion follows, assuming it is a correct criterion?
2. Are there any examples, in which inclusion maps for sum objects are not monos in the category? If yes, could you please describe it for me?

Thank you.

Comment: If $\operatorname{Hom}(B, A)$ is nonempty then $A \to A \amalg B$ is even a split monomorphism.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is true, which would mean that at least one of inclusions will be a split mono.

Comment: The statement also happens to be true in the category of groups, though that category does not satisfy your criterion (for example $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$ are incomparable).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Do you mean, inclusion maps for any sum object in the category of groups are monos....?

Answer (score 7):

Answer for (2): In the opposite category to the category of sets, $\mathrm{Sets}^{op}$, not all maps $A \to A \amalg B$ are monomorphisms.  For example, the canonical map $X^{op} \to X^{op} \amalg \emptyset^{op} \simeq (X \times \emptyset)^{op}$ corresponds to $\pi_1^{op}$ for the projection $\pi_1 : X \times \emptyset \to X$.  Since $\pi_1$ is not an epimorphism in the case where $X \ne \emptyset$, it follows that $\pi_1^{op}$ is not a monomorphism.

Another example for (2): In the category of commutative rings, the coproduct is the tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$: $X \amalg Y \simeq X \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} Y$.  However, for example $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}) \simeq 0$, so neither of the maps $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \to (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})$ or $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z} \to (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})$ is a monomorphism.  (If you are not familiar with tensor products, here's an elementary way of seeing $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}) \amalg (\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}) \simeq 0$: suppose you have any ring $R$ with homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \to R$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z} \to R$.  Then the existence of the first map implies $1_R + 1_R = 0_R$, whereas the existence of the second map implies $1_R + 1_R + 1_R = 0_R$.  Therefore, combining the two, $1_R = 0_R$ which implies $R \simeq 0$.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Poor me, I am not so well-versed in opposite categories. Thanks to you, now I have the motivation to get myself familiar with these. I hope to get back to soon.

Comment: @jaspreet I just added another example in the category of commutative rings, which might be more familiar to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the time that you kindly spent helping me. Unfortunately, I am totally ignorant of these objects (Commutative rings), though I hear about them time to time from people like you. But it is kind of you to help. Moreover, opposite categories also motivate the notion of a kind of transformation of categories, perhaps equivalent to that of a functor.

Comment: If you are interested, it appears that the criterion could be relaxed as follows: Let $S$ be sum object for $A, B$ in some category with inclusion maps $i_A:A\rightarrow S, i_B:B\rightarrow S$. If there exists a pair of objects $X, Y$ such that ($A\leq X$ and $\exists f:B\rightarrow X$) and ($B\leq Y$ and $\exists g:A\rightarrow Y$), then inclusion maps must be monos. This also uses the fact that a mono can only be factored through a mono.